# sequelize-auto TypeError: connection.query(...).on is not a function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-auto

I tried to use [sequelize-auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) to automatically generate models from existing PostgreSQL tables for [SequelizeJS](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize).

```
npm install -g sequelize-auto pg
sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d myDatabase -h localhost -u myUsername -p 5432 -x myPassword -e postgres
```

However, it failed with error `TypeError: connection.query(...).on is not a function`

Note: I'm using the following library versions:

- sequelize-auto@0.4.29
- pg@7.4.3

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like that query.on has been removed from pg version 7.

The workaround for now is to downgrade pg to version 6, e.g., 6.4.2

```
npm install -g pg@6.4.2
```

Then sequelize-auto (of the latest version 0.4.29 for the time being) would work fine.